# Java play custom onServerError doesnt get trigger when exception is thrown inside exceptionally()

Tags: java, playframework

So i have a custom Error Handler class like below,

```
@Singleton
public class ErrorHandler implements HttpErrorHandler {
    public CompletionStage<Result> onClientError(RequestHeader request, int statusCode, String message) {
        ...
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> onServerError(RequestHeader request, Throwable exception) {
        ObjectNode error = Json.newObject();
        error.put("message", exception.getMessage());
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
                Results.internalServerError(error)
        );
    }
}
```

In my controller, I have this:

```
public CompletionStage<Result> getGame(String id) {
    if (id.isEmpty()) {
        // this throw exception works as expected, it triggers the custom error handler
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no id is provided");
    }

    return thirdPartyService.getPost(id).thenApply(post-> {
        ...
    }).exceptionally(ex -> {
        // problem is here, it throw exception, but doesnt trigger the custom error handler
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex.toString());
    });
}
```

so in my code, there are 2 places where i throw exceptions.
the first one works fine, it triggers custom error handler.
but the second one, in side the exceptionally block, when "id" is invalid, it throws an exception, and i have verified that throw new ... that line is hit (verified by using break point.), but it doesnt trigger the custom error handler and whole app hangs

```
"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: ....exceptions.EmptyApiResultException: Post not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception has to be wrapped in a RuntimeException before being thrown since it is in the async part.

`throw new RuntimeException(new IllegalArgumentException(ex.toString()));`

Comment: thanks for the reply @sreeju, but the same issue still happens after applying your suggested change.

Comment: In this case, Can you try wrapping with a CompletionException instead of RuntimeException.